# ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified with TeamCity

Tags: sql, oracle, msbuild, teamcity

Presently, I am attempting to setup TeamCity.  In TeamCity Parameters, I have set the following values:

```
env.DeployConnectionString:  Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=mySID)));User ID=sys;Password=mySysPassword;
env.Rdbms: Oracle
env.SqlPlusLogon: @mySID
```

When I run the TeamCity project, it produces this error:

```
C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\4832a5599bdcf4b9\myProject\myProject.proj(51, 7): error MSB3073: The command "sqlplus "sys/mySysPassword@mySID as sysdba" @KillSessions.sql C:\Database\Oracle" exited with code -1.
```

Also, when I try to login to sqlplus from the command line, with the same arguments, it fails with the error in the above subject line.  When I attempt to login to sqlplus from the command line using this string, it works with no problem:

```
sqlplus sys/mySysPassword@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=mySID))) AS SYSDBA @KillSessions.sql
```

So my question is, how can I configure TeamCity to use the bottom connection string instead of the top one?  I had thought that is what I was doing in setting env.DeployConnectionString.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help.  Resolved the above problem by changing env.SqlPlusLogon to:

```
env.SqlPlusLogon: @(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=mySID)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not reading the SID at this command: sys/mySysPassword@mySID.

Why not store the SID in the tnsnames.ora, and replace the mySID part in your command line?